# Hovering over divA to affect divB

Tags: html, css

I have a logo with 2 div's - the icon and text. By default, the text is hidden, and should only be revealed when the user hovers their mouse over the icon. Unfortunately it's not working.

This is my HTML code:

```
<h1 class="site-title"><a href="http://localhost/themes/" rel="home">
    <div id="logo-icon">
        <img src="http://localhost/themes/wp-content/theme/img/logo_icon.png" class="anim">
    </div>
    <div id="logo-text">
        <img src="http://localhost/themes/wp-content/theme/img/logo_text.png" class="anim">
    </div>
</a></h1>
```

The CSS:

```
#logo-text, #logo-icon {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
#logo-text img.anim {
    opacity: 0;
}
#logo-icon img:hover #logo-text img.anim {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your markup, you might just want to let the user hover over the h1 to trigger the animation.

```
#logo-text, #logo-icon {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
#logo-text img.anim {
    opacity: 0;
}
.site-title:hover #logo-text img.anim {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aJHDV/).

Answer (score 0):

Css works only downwards in the DOM tree, what you would need to do is have

```
.site-title:hover img.anim{opacity: 1;}
```

what your code is looking for is a #logo-text beneath img:hover.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to nest those two, if your design accomodates it:

This requires one to be a child of the other:

```
logo-icon img:hover #logo-text img.anim
```

So something like this for your DOM:

```
<h1 class="site-title"><a href="http://localhost/themes/" rel="home">
    <div id="logo-icon">
        <img src="http://localhost/themes/wp-content/theme/img/logo_icon.png" class="anim" />
        <div id="logo-text">
            <img src="http://localhost/themes/wp-content/theme/img/logo_text.png" class="anim" />
        </div>
    </div>    
</a></h1>
```

Also, you should close your image tags.